# Cross Sliding doesn't work in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am working to enable Horizontal swipe / flick horizontally in my UWP app. I have followed MSDN link to add `GestureRecognizer`. It works well, If I have only `Grid` and `TextBlock` control in my XAML Page. However, I have `Grid` and `ListBox` in my XAML Page. It doesn't work with `ListBox`

Here is a sample;

class GestureInputProcessor
        {
            Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer;
            UIElement element;

```
        public GestureInputProcessor(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer gr, Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement target)
        {
            gestureRecognizer = gr;
            element = target;

            gestureRecognizer.GestureSettings =
                Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.Tap |
                Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.Hold | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.RightTap |
                Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.CrossSlide;

            // Set up pointer event handlers. These receive input events that are used by the gesture recognizer.
            element.PointerCanceled += OnPointerCanceled;
            element.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
            element.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
            element.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

            // Set up event handlers to respond to gesture recognizer output
            Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds threshold = new Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds();
            threshold.SelectionStart = 2;
            threshold.SpeedBumpStart = 3;
            threshold.SpeedBumpEnd = 4;
            threshold.RearrangeStart = 5;

            gestureRecognizer.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
            gestureRecognizer.CrossSlideThresholds = threshold;
            gestureRecognizer.CrossSliding += GestureRecognizer_CrossSliding;
        }
        private void GestureRecognizer_CrossSliding(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlidingEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageService.showMessage("You are here", MessageType.Information);
        }
        void OnPointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Route teh events to the gesture recognizer
            gestureRecognizer.ProcessDownEvent(args.GetCurrentPoint(element));
            // Set the pointer capture to the element being interacted with
            element.CapturePointer(args.Pointer);
            // Mark the event handled to prevent execution of default handlers
            args.Handled = true;
        }

        void OnPointerCanceled(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            gestureRecognizer.CompleteGesture();
            args.Handled = true;
        }

        void OnPointerReleased(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            gestureRecognizer.ProcessUpEvent(args.GetCurrentPoint(element));
            args.Handled = true;
        }

        void OnPointerMoved(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            gestureRecognizer.ProcessMoveEvents(args.GetIntermediatePoints(element));
        }


    }
```

XAML Page;

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <ListBox x:Name="lsbReadingChapter" ItemsSource="{Binding ChapterContent}"             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAya}" DoubleTapped="lsbReadingChapter_DoubleTapped"
                FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Visiblity}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="{Binding TranslationLanguage.FlowDirection}" FontSize="{Binding TranslationFont.FontSize}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="{Binding TranslationFont.FontPath}" Text="{Binding AyaTranslation}">
              </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

XAML Page Contstructor

```
  //Handle horizental / vertical swipe event
  GestureRecognizer gr1 = GestureRecognizer();

  public MainPage()
  {
    //swipe event this works well, If I have TextBlock instead of ListBox
    GestureInputProcessor ShapeInput1 = new GestureInputProcessor(gr1, LayoutRoot);   
  }
```

The pointer events are also fired in `ListBox` but the gesture doesn't work. I am looking to enable swipe left / right in my `Listbox` control. is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: In my view, this gesture may be caught first by the `ScrollView` of a `ListBox`, so can't it work with `ListBox`, we will continue to find a workaround method to solve this problem.

Comment: Firstly, I think listbox is an old control you should use listview for the best experience.  Secondly, can you use a Pivot to make your experience?  That's the platform control used to swipe thru tabs.

Comment: Thank you, @GraceFeng-MSFT I hope there is a work around for UWP in this issue. The same can be solved in WP8 Silverlight using Microsoft Phone Toolkit. Quincy I would see if I can work with ListView, however, I am sorry I cannot use Pivot for my situation.

Comment: @ARH Do you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156189/listview-swipe-slide-animation/30240055#30240055